# net use command works in command prompt, but not in bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-server-2008-r2, net-use

- It's a small laboratory network that connects to another network via an FTP server.
- FTP server is managed by the other network.
- This lab network is basically 2 clients and one server with several other IP devices connected.
- This lab server has Active Directory installed on it.
- We have an account on each network. The names of these acct's are the same for each network, and they have the same password.
- Password does have a % sign and a $ sign in it.
- Trying to map drive at startup on the lab server to point to the FTP server.
- Lab server is logged in with local admin acct.
- Command I'm using to map drive:
  net use j: \x.x.x.x\LabTransfer /user:\username "password"

This command will work when typed in a command prompt;
BUT fails to run when ran in a .bat file or .cmd file

Error message: "System error 86 has occured. The specified password is not correct.

Why would the net use command work at a command prompt and not in the .bat file?

Answer (score 3):

> The percent sign (`%`) is a special case. On the command line, it does not need quoting or escaping unless two of them are used to indicate a variable, such as `%OS%`. But in a batch file, you have to use a double percent sign (`%%`) to yield a single percent sign (`%`). Enclosing the percent sign in quotation marks or preceding it with caret does not work.
>
> […]
>
> - `echo The ratio was 47%`
>
>   - If run from a batch, the percent sign is ignored.
> - `echo The ratio was 47%%`
>
>   - If run from a batch, the percent sign is output once.

<sup>([source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping))</sup>

Comment: the password is similar to: a1b2c3$d4e5%f6g7 
The whole password is also enclosed in "quotes". Like this: "a1b2c3$d4e5%f6g7"
I use this same form in both the cmd line and batch file.
SO, on Monday I'll give the double percent sign %% a try in the batch file and post my results.
Thank you